# pandas tricky intra-column logic

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, cumsum

I have a DataFrame with three columns, `t`, `b` and `h`:

```
              t          b           h
0           NaN      False           6
1      6.023448      False          38
2     12.996233      False          46
3      2.484907      False          67
4      5.062595      False          81
5      4.624973      False          82
6      3.367296      False          38
7      3.688879      False          53
8      6.926577       True          38
9     14.972346      False          81
10    14.442651      False          78
11     3.367296      False          67
12     5.236442      False          46
13     5.298317       True           8
```

and I'd like to generate a new column which propagates the value of every instance of `h` for which `b==True`, backwards, and only  up to the next such instance or the first occurrence of `t>9.5`. The rest filled with `NaN`'s. Here's an example of the output I need:

```
              t          b           h       i
0           NaN      False           6     NaN
1      6.023448      False          38     NaN
2     12.996233      False          46      38
3      2.484907      False          67      38
4      5.062595      False          81      38
5      4.624973      False          82      38
6      3.367296      False          38      38
7      3.688879      False          53      38
8      6.926577       True          38      38
9     14.972346      False          81     NaN
10    14.442651      False          78       8
11     3.367296      False          67       8
12     5.236442      False          46       8
13     5.298317       True           8       8
```

I'd like to avoid iterating over rows because I have millions of them. I tried getting the `b==True` instances with `where` and then `fillna` with bfill option, but can't tell him when to start filling. Also, this will be `apply`'ed to individual groups within a `groupby`, so I need a function that adds a column to its argument and returns the entire frame

```
def get_i(x):
    x['i']=x['h'].where(x['b']==True).fillna(value=None,method='backfill').dropna()
    return x
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
#create NaN where False values
df['i'] = np.where(df.b, df.h, np.nan)
#bfill all NaN
df['i'] = df.i.fillna(method='bfill')

#create NaN by condition
a = df[::-1].groupby('i')['t'].apply(lambda x: (x > 9.5).shift().cumsum()) >= 1
df['i'] = df.i.mask(a, np.nan)

print (df)
            t      b   h     i
0         NaN  False   6   NaN
1    6.023448  False  38   NaN
2   12.996233  False  46  38.0
3    2.484907  False  67  38.0
4    5.062595  False  81  38.0
5    4.624973  False  82  38.0
6    3.367296  False  38  38.0
7    3.688879  False  53  38.0
8    6.926577   True  38  38.0
9   14.972346  False  81   NaN
10  14.442651  False  78   8.0
11   3.367296  False  67   8.0
12   5.236442  False  46   8.0
13   5.298317   True   8   8.0
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I reverse the order of the dataframe. It made it simpler for me, but it's not necessary:

```
df = df.iloc[::-1]
```

In order to isolate the instances where `b == True`, I added a new column:

```
df['cum_b'] = df['b'].cumsum()
```

This means that I can group by `cum_b` to work on each instance separately.

I define a function that finds the first index where `t > 9.5`, and populates column `i` until that index:

```
def func(dfg):
    idx = max(dfg[dfg.t > 9.5].index, default=-1)
    dfg.loc[:, 'i'] = dfg.h.iloc[0]
    dfg.loc[dfg.index < idx, 'i'] = np.nan
    return dfg.i
```

Note how I use `max` and `index < idx` because I did not reset the index of the dataframe after reverting its order.

When I apply the function, I get your desired result:

```
In [44]: df.groupby('cum_b').apply(func)
Out[44]: 
cum_b    
1      13     8.0
       12     8.0
       11     8.0
       10     8.0
       9      NaN
2      8     38.0
       7     38.0
       6     38.0
       5     38.0
       4     38.0
       3     38.0
       2     38.0
       1      NaN
       0      NaN
```